# Handling TCP/IP Packet Splitting using Qt or Similar Libraries?

Tags: c++, qt, tcp, ros

I am trying to send TCP messages over my local network that exceed the MTU limit of ~1500 bytes. I know that TCP protocol splits messages exceeding 1500 bytes into individual packets at some level, but am unclear if it's something I need to deal with at the application level. So I wrote a test application in ROS and Qt, C++, to test the behavior. I picked these because they are what my overall project is written in.

My test_fragmentation_test node sets up a server, then the test_client node establishes a connection and sends a message exceeding 1500 bytes. The goal is to get the server to receive this full message as one cohesive unit.

When I test these nodes on the same computer, the server receives the full messages as one unit. However, when I put the server and client on separate computers (still same network), the  server receives the message as multiple packets. The packets are either 1500 bytes, or multiples thereof, so I believe they are sometimes getting squashed together in the read buffer in pairs of two or three.

Here is my code:

tcp_fragmentation_test.cpp

```
#include "ros/ros.h"

#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QTcpServer>
#include <QDebug>

//prototype functions
void initialConnect();
void receiveMessage();

//global(ish) variables
extern QTcpServer* subserver;
extern QTcpSocket* subsocket;
QTcpServer* subserver;
QTcpSocket* subsocket;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    //initiate ROS
    ros::init(argc, argv, "tcp_fragmentation_test_node");
    ros::NodeHandle n;

    subserver = new QTcpServer();
    //call initialConnect on first connection attempt
    QObject::connect(subserver, &QTcpServer::newConnection,initialConnect);
    quint16 server_port = 9998;
    //start listening
    QHostAddress server_IP = QHostAddress("127.0.0.1");
    //start listening for incoming C2 connections
    if(!subserver->listen(server_IP, server_port))
    {
        qDebug().noquote() << "subserver failed to start on: " + server_IP.toString() + "/" + QString::number(server_port);
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug().noquote() << "subserver started on: " + server_IP.toString() + "/" + QString::number(server_port);
    }


    return app.exec(); //inifite loop that starts qt event listener
}

//accept incoming connection
void initialConnect() 
{
    //accept the incoming connection
    subsocket = subserver->nextPendingConnection();
    
    QObject::connect(subsocket, &QTcpSocket::readyRead, receiveMessage);
}

void receiveMessage()
{
    //read data in
    QByteArray received_message = subsocket->readAll();
    qDebug() << "message received: ";
    qDebug() << received_message;

}
```

test_client.cpp

```
#include "ros/ros.h"

#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QTcpServer>
#include <QDebug>

//function prototypes
bool initialConnect(QString server_IP, quint16 server_port);
void sendMessage(QByteArray message);

//global(ish) variables
QTcpSocket* test_socket;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);


    ros::init(argc, argv, "test_client");
    ros::NodeHandle n;

    initialConnect("127.0.0.1",9998);
    //send 1500+ byte message, to test IP fragmentation
    sendMessage("<message large than 1500 bytes>");


    return app.exec(); //inifite loop that starts qt event listener
}

bool initialConnect(QString server_IP, quint16 server_port)
{
    //create test_socket
    test_socket = new QTcpSocket();

    //try to connect, then wait a bit to make sure it was successful
    test_socket->connectToHost(server_IP, server_port); 
    if(test_socket->waitForConnected(1000))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Failed to connect to server";
        return false;
    }
}

//send test message
void sendMessage(QByteArray message)
{
    //send message
    test_socket->write(message);
    test_socket->waitForBytesWritten(1000);

    return;
}
```

I talked to one of my colleagues about this, and they said that they had not run into this issue when sending messages that exceed the MTU in both Tcl scripting language, and HTML websockets. They sent me their code to check out, but unfortunately it is a small part of a really large and not well documented codebase, so I am having parsing out what they did and why they did not run into the same issues as me.

I know that I could probably avoid this issue by including identifying headers for each message, that include the length, and then combine read messages into an overall buffer until the correct number of bytes have been read. However, I'm trying to see if there's a simpler way than this, especially after my colleague telling me that he never ran into this issue. It seems like something that should be handled behind the scenes by the TCP protocol, and I'm trying to avoid dealing with it at the application level if at all possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: TCP/IP is a stream not a packet protocol (at the top of the protocol stack).  All you can rely on is that you will get the bytes in the same sequence as they were sent.

Comment: What you need isn't a way to avoid "fragmentation" (in quotes because what you are seeing isn't fragmentation, but rather just the way TCP works).  Your receiver will need to be intelligent enough to handle receiving varying sizes of bytes at a time, in the way you mention in your final paragraph.   (btw I agree that TCP *should* handle this, since as it stands every programmer ends up having to reinvent the wheel again... but it doesn't, so here we are)

Comment: There are two simple solutions to handle this: 1. A message consists always of a fix header with the size of bytes and the resp. pay load or 2. You define a language for your messages with a resp. parser on the receiver side which "knows" itself when a message is complete (according to its grammar rules).

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like you guys are all saying that I'm just going to have to deal with it at the application level. Thanks for the info. Still makes me wonder what my colleague did to avoid this issue, but I guess I'll ask him in more detail.

Comment: Do you guys think that I need to checksum my messages as well? Or is it enough to assume that once I have the number of bytes that I sent on the receiving end, I have the whole message? (i.e. assuming that TCP will have them in the right order and not have dropped any and then filled in the ending bytes with the next message down the pipe without at least throwing an error)

Comment: @JohnDoe With TCP/IP you should always receive the data as sent, or receive no data at all.  Packets are numbered and the protocol stack will retry missing/corrupt packets (without you knowing) and reassemble the data stream in the correct order.

Comment: Great, that's good news! So it sounds like I will need to 1) differentiate messages with some kind of unique header, 2) include a unique message end flag, or alternatively include the message length in the header and 3) send back confirmation upon receipt so that the sender knows the receiver has received. 
But I don't have to checksum the received message? Does this sound right?